# Firebase emulator com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$WrongAbiError

Tags: mapbox-android, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to test a basic Android application (Kotlin) with the Mapbox Android library.  My instrumented tests pass on an emulator running on my development laptop.  But they fail on Firebase's test lab running emulators.  They pass on Firebase's test lab running physical devices.

I get the following exception on Firebase test lab emulators Nexus5X and Pixel2:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver.instance(ConnectivityReceiver.java:43)
>   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:67) at
>   com.locuslabs.sdk.llpublic.LLMapFragment.onCreateView(LLMapFragment.kt:61)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
>   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
>   at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
>   at com.locuslabs.sdktestapp.MapActivity.onStart(MapActivity.kt:74) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
>   at
>   androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:714)
>   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:525)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:484)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:236)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:162)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:139)
>   at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:170) at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31) at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:47) at
>   androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:137)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:306)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:228)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:366)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:255)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:65)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:158)
>   at
>   androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:155)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) Caused
>   by: com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapStrictModeException: Map detected an error
>   that would fail silently otherwise: Failed to load native shared
>   library. - com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$WrongAbiError: APK was built
>   for a different platform at
>   com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapStrictMode.strictModeViolation(MapStrictMode.java:34)
>   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:49) at
>   com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.NativeConnectivityListener.(NativeConnectivityListener.java:13)

What is wrong with the emulators on Firebase test lab?  Why can't they load Mapbox's native code?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to completely diagnose this from just a stack trace. Are you building your app for an x86 target architecture? Are you using a split or universal APK?

I think the different behavior you are seeing is because Firebase Test Lab virtual devices run on x86, while the great majority of Android physical devices have ARM processors.

"Failed to load native shared library. - com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader$WrongAbiError: APK was built for a different platform" -- seems to indicate an issue with finding native ARM code rather than x86 code.

This page discusses a similar error situation: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5773

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How do I determine which architecture my app is built for?  How do I determine if I'm using split or universal APK?  I am probably using the default architecture and default choice for split or Universal APK because I created my app in Android Studio from one of its templates and I did not change these settings.

Comment: After reading about [splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) I am sure I'm not using splits so my app must be built as a Universal APK.  Bear in mind, the emulators available to Android Studio don't exhibit the problem.  The emulators available to Android Studio seem to run on x86 also, according to the CPU/ABI column I see when I go to "Tools" > "AVD Manager".  I guess the emulators on Firebase test Lab differ somehow from the ones in Android Studio.

Comment: What API levels have you tried this on for FTL virtual devices? I'm curious whether the same error message happens for all API levels.

Comment: Are you able to compile the MapBox library into x86 code? That would solve this issue. 

Or there may be a bug in Facebook's soloader. It is very hard to debug this from just the information available here.

Comment: P. Davis, I ran it on emulators for Nexus5X and Pixel2.  It was a while ago but I think the API level was 28.  I'm thinking it would be possible to reproduce with a basic app that implements Mapbox, for example their Android demo app at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo .